Displaying photo stored as blob in GPKG in QGIS layout

Can I display photo stored as blob in gpkg in QGIS layout to print?


You can load images from GPKG files by defining the image source via an Expression Function:
'base64:'|| to_base64(attribute(get_feature( '<GPKG layer name>','<filter field>','<filter value>'),'<blob field>'))

In your case i.e.
'base64:'|| to_base64(attribute(get_feature( 'your GPKG layer','FID','3'),'__blank__1'))

See example here: Read (and write) SVG from Geopackage with QGIS
To display the photos in feature forms, see answer here: Display photo stored as blob in GPKG

thanks you. but what is  and ?

 is the name of the GPKG column you will use to select your photo (i.e. FID), and  is the value (i.e. 1 ... FID=1).

thank you, I will try this

just vanished cicrle markers( points) on map . I couldn't display the images in Qgis layout

create a new image in your layout and use the expression editor to define the image source with the given expression.

Wow!!! Thank you

@artterrm if the answer solves your issue, please mark it as accepted.
